# Method Not Allowed when send html tag with attribute in Laravel POST API

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-8

I've been creating API using laravel version 8. I faced an issue that confused me for 4 hours. The issue is when i created an API with method POST and receive a html element tag for the payload. I've test it using postman in my local server and its return 200 as expected. But when i test it in my sharehosting, its return **405 Method Not Allowed**.

the method of the API Post for store Question looks like this:

```
class QuestionController extends Controller {

public function storeQuestion(Request $request) {
    // do some validation here
    
    $datas = $request['datas'];
    foreach($datas as $question):
        $newQuestion = new TbQuestion;
        $newQuestion->name = $question->name;

        // here the html tag payload for content field
        $newQuestion->content = $question->content;
        $newQuestion->save();
    endforeach;
}

}
```

this is my route

```
<?php

    $router->group(['middleware' => 'auth'], function() use ($router) {
        $router->post('/input/question', [
            'uses' => 'QuestionController@storeQuestion'
        ]);
    });
```

the data i've been sent using postman look like this

```
datas[0][name] = "Question number 1"
datas[0][content]  = <p style="color: rgb(0,0,0);">What the meaning of question?</p>
```

But i've realized that when i remove the quotation tag attribute of payload content just like this:

```
datas[0][content] = <p>What the meaning of question?</p>
```

and it's return as expected 200.

Is there anyone know about this issue?

I've tried to replace the vendor folder of app in share hosting using my vendor folder app, but it's not working, the one solution i've tried is to remove the attribute of an html tag in the content payload, but it's impossible cause the software requirement.

I want to know what the cause of this issue is and how to resolve it.

Comment: ```</p>``` create another route like ```api/question/{parameters}/p>``` because **slash(/)** is considered as new route for API

Comment: But when i send the payload with **slash** character or add `class` attribute, it work as well.  the problem came up when i tried to send payload using `style` attribute in a html tag.

Comment: Can you add also the image of the error in your network preview to check the error message?

Comment: try to use single quotation around the content like this :
datas[0][content]  = '<p style="color: rgb(0,0,0);">What the meaning of question?</p>'

Comment: Try looking for the logs on your shared hosting; this might be the result of poorly designed "smart" WAF (Web Application Firewall) software. I have seen lots of nonsense like this with "mod_security" (a recent example appeared to be blocking anything containing the word "get"!)

Comment: @AliIsmaeel I've tried to add single quotation but it didn't work

Comment: @IMSoP oke, i would try it

Comment: @Newbee the error it's like the 405 error page in laravel

Comment: What's the message?. Something like this? ```message
: 
"The POST method is not supported for this route. Supported methods: GET, HEAD."```

Answer (score 0):

I resolved my issue few hour ago, but this answer is still not inform the main cause of my issue in Laravel, so the resolve it's a bit tricky.

In my frontend, if there any content or payload like this:

```
let content = '<p style="color: rgb(0,0,0);">What the meaning of question?</p>';
```

I just replace the word `style=` using `style2=`, so the payload to be sent look like this:

```
let content = '<p style="color: rgb(0,0,0);">What the meaning of question?</p>';
content = content.replaceAll("style=", "style2=");
```

And in my controller Laravel App, i was replaced the word `style2=` to `style=` using this code:

```
class QuestionController extends Controller {

public function storeQuestion(Request $request) {
    // do some validation here
    
    $datas = $request['datas'];
    foreach($datas as $question):
        $newQuestion = new TbQuestion;
        $newQuestion->name = $question->name;

        // find if there any word style2=, replace with style=
        $content = $question->content;
        $content = preg_replace("style2=", "style=", $content);
        $newQuestion->content = $content;
        $newQuestion->save();
    endforeach;
}

}
```

And when i tried the code, magically it's work as expected.